# Scrapy spider_idle signal not received in my extension

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-signal

I have common behaviour between several spiders on `spider_idle` signal being received, and I would like to move this behaviour into an extension.

My extension already listens for `spider_opened` and `spider_closed` signals successfully. However, the `spider_idle` signal is not received.

Here is my extension (edited for brevity):

```py
import logging
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
from scrapy import signals

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyExtension(object):

    def __init__(self, settings, stats):
        self.settings = settings
        self.stats = stats

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):

        # instantiate the extension object
        ext = cls(crawler.settings, crawler.stats)

        # connect the extension object to signals
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)

        # return the extension object
        return ext

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        logger.info("start logging spider %s", spider.name)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        logger.info("end logging spider %s", spider.name)

    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        logger.info("idle logging spider %s", spider.name)

        # attempt to crawl orphaned products
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host=self.settings['AWS_RDS_HOST'],
                             port=self.settings['AWS_RDS_PORT'],
                             user=self.settings['AWS_RDS_USER'],
                             passwd=self.settings['AWS_RDS_PASSWD'],
                             db=self.settings['AWS_RDS_DB'],
                             cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
                             use_unicode=True,
                             charset="utf8",)
        c=db.cursor()

        c.execute("""SELECT p.url FROM products p LEFT JOIN product_data pd ON p.id = pd.product_id AND pd.scrape_date = CURDATE() WHERE p.website_id = %s AND pd.id IS NULL""", (spider.website_id,))

        while True:
            product = c.fetchone()
            if product is None:
                break
            # record orphaned product
            self.stats.inc_value('orphaned_count')
            yield self.crawler.engine.crawl(Request(url=product['url'], callback=spider.parse_item), spider)
        db.close()
```

Why is the signal not being received?

**Update**

As requested, here's some more info.

This is my `settings.py`:

```py
BOT_NAME = 'myproject'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['myproject.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'myproject.spiders'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 610,
    'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
}

AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 2
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 30
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0 

EXTENSIONS = {
    'myproject.extensions.MyExtension': 500,
}
```

I get the same issue whether the rotating_proxy middleware is enabled or not.

This is an example spider I'm testing with:

```py
import scrapy
from furl import furl
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from myproject.items import MyProjectItem


class ScrapeThisSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "scrapethis"
    website_id = 5
    custom_settings = {
        'IMAGES_STORE': 's3://myproject-dev/images/scrapethis/',
        'LOG_FILE': 'scrapethis.log',
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'DEBUG',
    }
    allowed_domains = ['scrapethis.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.scrapethis.co.uk']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)

    def customise_url(link):
        f = furl(link)
        f.args['ar'] = '3'
        return f.url

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=('articleId=', ), process_value=customise_url)),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('articleId=', ), process_value=customise_url), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        price = response.xpath("//article[@class='productbox'] //strong[@class='pricefield__price']//text()").extract()

        item = MyProjectItem()
        f = furl(response.url)
        item['id'] = f.args['articleId']
        item['spider'] = self.name
        item['price'] = price
        return item
```

**Update 2**

I think I have discovered what is causing the `spider_idle` signal to fail - in my method, I'm connecting to an Amazon RDS database, querying it and processing the results.

If I comment out the code, my signal runs (I get the log entry), if my query code remains, the signal does not run (or at least, I get no log entry).

It's strange, because the first thing I do in my method is to log the signal?

**Update 3**

I've discovered if I remove the `yield` keyword in my query result loop, it works - but only 1 request is made. I need each of the urls returned in my query to be added to the crawler. (Apologies if I'm asking anything stupid - I'm still rather new to Python and scrapy).

Comment: How have you activated the extension in settings? Also how are you using the code in current approach?

Comment: I can see the log message with your extension (same exact code) within a simple `scrapy startproject` + `scrapy genspider example example.com`. If you can provide code for reproducing this missing log line that would be great.

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes, my extension is enabled and i get the other log entries (start and end spider), just not my idle entry. I was using the signal in the spider itself, but repeating the code

Comment: @paultrmbrth could something else in spiders be blocking the spider idle signal? I'm not implementing signal in the spider, just the extension. I'm just calling my spider normally `scrapy crawl myspider`

Comment: Without spider code or the full extension, hard to say. With the code you provided, I cannot reproduce it. Maybe others can.

Comment: looks like there is nothing wrong with this particular extension. Can you share your settings file? Also, is the spider running also enabling its own idle signal?

Comment: @eLRuLL I've shared the relevant bit of my `settings.py`, along with an example spider. The spider doesn't listen for any signals.

Comment: @eLRuLL I have found the issue - see Update 2 in question. It's related to actions in the signal handler method. However, I get no errors, and the very first thing I do in the method is log the signal. Anything else I can try?

Comment: @BrynJ you are right, removing the `yield` should fix it. That method doesn't return anything, so there is nothing to "yield", also remember that using `self.crawler.engine.crawl` is kind of a hack, to add requests into the scheduler queue, used when you want to add requests outside the spider methods.

Comment: @eLRuLL thanks for confirming. So, the reason it only adds (or attempts) to add one url is actually because of an error. `AttributeError: 'MyExtension' object has no attribute 'crawler'`- so how do I access the crawler in my extension?

Comment: you can access it from the spider, `spider.crawler`

Comment: great thanks @eLRuLL - all working as expected now

Comment: @BrynJ Could you please move your solution out of your question and into an answer?